# HTML5 download attribute setting filename only on Right click + Save as

Tags: javascript, html

I provide direct links to files stored on external services - Youtube, Soundcloud, Vimeo etc, but filename is not overwritten in download attribute and saved as fileID or videoplayback. Only when Right click + Save as is used, filename is correct.

```html
<a href=​"https:​/​/​r2---sn-uhvcpax0n5-co5l.googlevideo.com/​videoplayback?id=fd988d…,source,requiressl,pcm2cms,mm,mn,pl,ms,mv,ratebypass,mime,gir,clen,lmt,dur" download=​"Led Zeppelin - Since I've Been Loving You Live (HD)​-_ZiN_NqT-Us.mp4">​download - 7.23 MB​</a>​
```

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Google chrome. I know that IE or Safari don't support download attribute

Answer (score 2):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) not all browsers support download attribute yet and some have limited or buggy support.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it respect the norm about the `download` attribute: the filename that you defined will be used only if the URI of the link has the same origin of the current page.